# Why can a bash function recursively call itself without using local variables?

Tags: bash, function

I am doing scripts in bash. It is said in this site (http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/recurnolocvar.html) that "A function may recursively call itself even without use of local variables." but it was not explained why.

There is a sample function involving the fibonacci sequence. He commented on the code that it doesnt need to be local and asked why, but did not answer. A part is shown below:

```
Fibonacci ()
{
idx=$1   # Doesn't need to be local. Why not?
if [ "$idx" -lt "$MINIDX" ]
then
echo "$idx"  # First two terms are 0 1 ... see above.
else
(( --idx ))  # j-1
term1=$( Fibonacci $idx )   #  Fibo(j-1)

(( --idx ))  # j-2
term2=$( Fibonacci $idx )   #  Fibo(j-2)

echo $(( term1 + term2 ))
fi
}
```

The Fibonacci function has an "idx" variable which could have been modified by successive calls because the successive "idx" definitions are not declared local, hence it should affect the previous definitions.

The previous topic on that site (http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/localvar.html) demonstrates that if a variable is not declared as local (therefore defaults to global) then changing it would reflect changes in global scope.

Why can a bash function recursively call itself without using local variables?

Comment: Beginners are advised to avoid the ABS because of misleading explanations like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the variables effectively are local.

The command in process substitution (`$()`) is run by a subshell. Variable values don't propagate back from subshell. So the recursive calls can't affect the parent call.

Commands run in subshell are:

- process substitution (`$(command)`)
- *both* sides of a pipeline (`command1 | command2`)
- explicit subshell (`(command)`)
- background jobs (`command&`)
- (bash-specific) process redirections (`>(command)`, `<(command)`)

There is *no* way to propagate any variable values back from these.

Comment: Regarding the second bullet point, one can use `shopt -s lastpipe` to run the last command of a pipeline in the current shell rather than a subshell. (This is bash-specific.)

Answer (score 1):

It's because he calls the function recursively through a subshell:

```
term1=$( Fibonacci $idx )   #  Fibo(j-1)
```

I actually find that inefficient For every level of recursion, a process is summoned and could cause overload to the system. It's better to use local variables.

Comment: It's inefficient in the first place because it uses the naive exponential algorithm.